# crossdomain ajax call with Jquery 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, https, cross-domain

Actually, I dont know if it's a crossdomain ajax problem. 
Here is my problem:
I have a website running under ssl protocol, for example, the website url address is: https://172.11.8.1:10443/index.php, now I would like to get some xml data from another http process in the same server, say: http://172.11.8.1:8080/test.xml.

My assumption is, I could just add a js file in the HTML page of https://172.11.8.1:10443/index.php, the core ajax call is like the following:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://172.11.8.1:8080/test.xml",
    dataType:"xml",
    success: xmlParser,
    error: errHandler
});

   function xmlParser (xml, textStatus)
   {
     //
   }

   function errHandler(xhr, statusText, error)
   {
   if (xhr.status == "0" && statusText == "error")
   {
      alert("network down");
   }
   else if (xhr.status == "200" && statusText == "parseerror")
   {
          alert("error to get xml info");
   }
else
{
        alert("error to get xml info");
}
}
```

as I follow the js file, it's always go into error handle function directly. And the error information is like:

```
    errorType  Error: a is null message=a is null
    statusText parsererror
```

I believe the XML file format is valid, because I tried the same ajax call under the same http domain, it works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around the cross-domain issue in this case ... just create a page in (for example) php that gets the feed....

**getXml.php**

```
<?php die(file_get_contents('http://172.11.8.1:8080/test.xml')); ?>
```

**js**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'getXml.php',
    dataType:"xml",
    success: xmlParser,
    error: errHandler
});
```

Comment: I simplified the question like that, actually the xml is not statically existed in the same server. I dont know if it's possible to solve this problem only with client side js?

Comment: oh, actually I think it might be more complicated than I thought. I just tried your method, you could run getXml.php in terminal without any problems, however if you call https://172.11.8.1:10443/getXml.php, it seems firefox never got responses (loading for 5 mins already). I dont know how to explain this

Comment: Do any pages on that domain work? Does PHP Work? Does `echo 'test';` work?

Comment: sure, all other pages work. you may try setup a http and https server and do some simple experiments and you will know what I mean

Comment: So this is not a `crossdomain` issue at all... this is a security protocol conflict.